# Static Files Under the Same Domain with Django

Tags: django, heroku, cdn, django-staticfiles, static-files

[Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files) recommends serving static content from a seperate server. I'd like the domain of my static files to be the same as my Django server's (including subdomain). Is this possible? If it matters, I'm on Heroku.

I'm looking for a solution that agrees with both the recommendations provided by Django's documentation and Heroku's. Django recommends creating a separate server—preferably nginx or Apache. Heroku only lets you use the same domain only by using python or other high-level solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the extremely comprehensive documentation on Heroku's site on how to serve static files with Django? Not a mention of a separate server.

Comment: I did. I found no solution that agreed with *both* the recommendations provided by Django's documentation and Heroku's. Django recommends creating a separate server—preferably nginx or apache. As far as I can tell, Heroku only lets you create a separate server to serve from a different domain.

Comment: Part of the reason for using a separate server is so that they are also hosted under a different domain. This is to avoid the problem where request headers are bloated with cookies that aren't needed when requesting static resources. By being under a separate domain the cookies aren't set, due to it being a different domain, and things will be more efficient as requests are smaller. Overall though, most peoples sites don't get enough traffic that it matters anyway. So just use WhiteNoise WSGI middleware with Django to host the static files.

Comment: @graham Google, for instance, hosts its static files under the same domain. There is a real risk the server will need to handle a lot of traffic. Are you saying it's impossible to host a Django app with static files under the same domain?

Comment: It is not impossible, but just warning that if you do, the HTTP request headers will contain extra stuff related to cookies that is not needed and just means using more network bandwidth. I wouldn't compare it to Google as you have no idea how they handle the routing of requests. Static file requests are likely filtered out very quickly and not treated in same way as the dynamic requests for the actual application.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Actually I do know how it worked; I worked at Google. It's a good approach for a number of reasons. Specifically, in Django, how do I do this?

Comment: I already mentioned above to use the WhiteNoise WSGI middleware with Django.

Comment: WhiteNoise uses python, which is horribly inefficient compared to nginx, Apache or a traditional CDN service. The problem was to serve files without using python or other high-level solutions. Is it possible to do this?